# Why java Date comparison returns false when it is 00:00 AM?

Tags: java, android, date

I am comparing a date object with two date objects. I want to know that the object lies within the range. So here is my code to compare:
I will get three date objects, one belongs to my current time, other two belongs to before and after time.

```
  public String calcOpenClosed(String timeRange, Date currentTime)
{


    Log.e("current time got", currentTime.getHours()+" "+currentTime.getMinutes());
    if(timeRange.contains(","))
    {

        String[] slot = timeRange.split(",");
        String[] range1 = slot[0].split("-");
        String[] range2 = slot[1].split("-");
        Date date1;
        Date date2;
        Date date3;
        Date date4;
        Log.e("range 1", range1[0]);
        Log.e("range 2", range1[1]);
        Log.e("range 3", range2[0]);
        Log.e("range 4", range2[1]);

        date1 = getTime(range1[0]);
        date2 = getTime(range1[1]);
        date3 = getTime(range2[0]);
        date4 = getTime(range2[1]);

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal4 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(date1);
        cal2.setTime(date2);
        cal3.setTime(date3);
        cal4.setTime(date4);
        Calendar curr = Calendar.getInstance();
        curr.setTime(currentTime);

        if(curr.after(cal1) && curr.before(cal2) || curr.after(cal3) && curr.after(cal4))
        {
            return "OPEN NOW";
        }
        else
        {
            return "CLOSED";
        }
    }
    else
    {

        String[] range = timeRange.split("-");
        Date date1;
        Date date2;
        date1 = getTime(range[0]);
        date2 = getTime(range[1]);

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal1.setTime(date1);
        cal2.setTime(date2);

        Calendar curr = Calendar.getInstance();
        curr.setTime(currentTime);

        if(curr.after(cal1) || curr.before(cal2))
        {
            return "OPEN NOW";
        }
        else
        {
            return "CLOSED";
        }
    }
}

public Date getTime(String timeCreated) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String date = year + "-" +(month<10?("0"+month):(month)) +"-"+day;
    String timeCreatedSlot[] = timeCreated.split(" ");
    String[] splittedTime = timeCreatedSlot[0].split(":");
    int time = Integer.parseInt(splittedTime[0]);
    String timeNow = String.valueOf(time<10?("0"+time):(time));
    String finalTime = date + " "+ timeNow + ":" + splittedTime[1]+  " "+timeCreatedSlot[1];
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aaa");

    try {
        Date timeCreatedDate = dateFormat.parse(finalTime);
        Log.e("time created", timeCreatedDate.getHours()+"");
        return timeCreatedDate;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("exception", "setTimestamp: " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));

    }
    return null;
}
```

Its working fine but its giving me wrong result when the time range is 4:00 AM - 00:00 AM. The above code I have tried with date.before and date.after also. But giving same result.

Comment: When you stepped through your code with a debugger for the input time range of 4:00-00:00, what did you find that didn't behave the way it should? Why? What confuses you about that behavior?

Comment: When I am having current time 23:00 and time range is 4 PM to 12AM, its giving me wrong response, its should give me true whereas its giving me false.

Comment: which line gives the unexpected result?

Comment: 00:00 AM if the same month, day, and year is earlier than 04:00 AM. So unless the month, day, and year of the "00:00" is after that of the "04:00", you will have an empty range. Unfortunately you have not provided enough information in our question to know if that's what is going on. Please clarify.

Comment: Way too much code. Try to strip it down to the bare essentials when posting to StackOverflow. We are here to solve specific programming problems, not review your code. [See MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

First, separate your String handling from the date-time code. Get the Strings parsed into date-time objects, then hand-off those objects to a separate logic method. And you’ll make your life easier if you avoid a heavy reliance on strings and instead pass around objects.

Secondly, you are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

If you are trying to focus on opening-closing times as generic time-of-day values rather than specific date-time moments, use the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

```
LocalTime openingTime = LocalTime.parse ( "04:00" );
LocalTime closingTime = LocalTime.parse ( "00:00" );
Boolean inRange = null;
LocalTime target = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT; // LocalTime.of ( 3 , 0) or LocalTime.of ( 4 , 0) or LocalTime.of ( 5 , 0) or LocalTime.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Los_Angeles" ) );
if ( closingTime.equals ( LocalTime.MIDNIGHT ) ) {
    inRange = (  ! target.isBefore ( openingTime ) );
} else {
    inRange = ( (  ! target.isBefore ( openingTime ) ) && ( target.isBefore ( closingTime ) ) );
}
```

Or you can write that logic on a single line. Personally I would stick with the if-else construct.

```
Boolean inRange2 = ( (  ! target.isBefore ( openingTime ) ) && ( closingTime.equals ( LocalTime.MIDNIGHT ) ? true : target.isBefore ( closingTime ) ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "openingTime: " + openingTime + " | closingTime: " + closingTime + " | target: " + target + " | inRange: " + inRange + " | inRange2: " + inRange2 );
```

In real-world work I would verify inputs by checking for the closing time being *after* the opening (or equal to LocalTime.MIDNIGHT as the only exception).

## Half-Open

The code above takes the Half-Open approach to interpreting a span of time as the beginning being *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This is sensible common practice in date-time work.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.